# Move Element of a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I would like to move elements in a list in prolog to a new location within the same list, similar to a cut & paste operation.

For example, if i have the list [1,2,3,4,5]

I want something like:

```
move(List, D1, D2, D3, Newlist)
```

List = original list, D1 = from what element, D2 = to what element of the list, D3 destination in the list.

An example:

```
move([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 1, 3, 5, NewList) :- (Implementation).

NewList = [4,5,1,2,3,6,7,8,9].
```

I made that for when D3 > D2, and something similar for the case when D2 < D3, but I think that I don't have it right.

```
% Move D3 > D2 & D2
move([X|L], D1, D2, D3, Resultado) :-
    movevalue([X|L], D1, D2, Z),
    moveinsert([X|L], Z, D3, ParteB),
    primerapartel([X|L], D3, PrimeraParte),
    deleting(PrimeraParte, D1, D2, ParteA),
    append(ParteA, ParteB, Resultado),
    !.

movevalue([X|L], D1, D2, Z) :-
    D1 > 1,
    E1 is D1 - 1,
    E2 is D2 - 1,
    movevalue(L, E1, E2, Z),
    !.
movevalue([X|L], 1, D2, [X|Z]) :-
    D2 > 0,
    E2 is D2 - 1,
    movevalue(L, 1, E2, Z).
movevalue([X|L], 1, 0, Z) :-
    Z = [].

moveinsert([X|L], Z, D3, Resultado) :-
    D3 > 1,
    E3 is D3 - 1,
    moveinsert(L, Z, E3, Resultado),
    !.
moveinsert([X|L], Z, 1, Resultado) :-
    append(Z,L,Resultado).

%append([X],Z,Resultado2)
%Primera parte L
primerapartel(_, 0, Resultado) :-
    Resultado = [], !.
primerapartel([X|L], N, [X|Resultado]) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    primerapartel(L, N1, Resultado),
    !.

deleting(Lista, D1, D2, Resultado) :-
    deletingizq(Lista, D1, D2, ResultadoA),
    deletingder(Lista, D1, D2, ResultadoB),
    append(ResultadoA, ResultadoB, Resultado),
    !.

deletingizq([Princi|Pal], D1, D2, [Princi|Resultado]) :-
    D1 > 1,
    E1 is D1 - 1,
    E2 is D2 - 1,
    deletingizq(Pal, E1, E2, Resultado).
deletingizq([X|L], 1, D2, Resultado) :-
    D2 > 1,
    E2 is D2-1,
    deletingizq(L, 1, E2, Resultado).
deletingizq([X|L], 1, 1, Resultado) :-
    Resultado = [].

deletingder([Princi|Pal], D1, D2, Resultado) :-
    D1 > 1,
    E1 is D1 - 1,
    E2 is D2 - 1,
    deletingder(Pal, E1, E2, Resultado).
deletingder([X|L], 1, D2, Resultado) :-
    D2 > 1,
    E2 is D2 - 1,
    deletingder(L, 1, E2, Resultado).
deletingder([X|L], 1, 1, Resultado) :-
    Resultado = L.
```

Comment: some effort from your side ?

Comment: @CapelliC Now I pasted what I do in one of the cases,I don't need that someone made the code,the idea on how to do it in a good way is when I'm lost,I get a solution but the problem is that I think that is not really the really best way to do that, I Didn't think for do that thing I expended 25 lines(when doing all the cases), I think that could be optimized, but I have been working with this for 2 days and didn't get a good advance on the way who solve it on the optimal way.
Thanks anyways for your answer :)

Comment: Putting each rule entirely on one line doesn't make for very readable code.

Comment: @MarceloCantos fixed! on the apge that you write,seems different that when it get posted!,anyway fixed

Comment: That made it worse. I've amended the question myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found the hard way that Prolog lists are not easy to handle by index.

To make the problem more declarative, and thus amenable to be solved in Prolog, I would separate the indexing from mapping, with the help of [length](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2)/2 and [nth1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth1/3)/3.

To begin, we know that Result will have the same length as List. Enforce this:

```
move(List, Start, Stop, Target, Result) :-
    length(List, N),
    length(Result, N),
    move_elements(1, N, List, Start, Stop, Target, Result).
```

Moving elements around requires mapping an index from List to Result, and we must do for each element:

```
/* edit: see the code below - this is buggy    
move_elements(I, N, _List, _Start, _Stop, _Target, _Result) :-
    I =:= N + 1.
move_elements(I, N, List, Start, Stop, Target, Result) :-
    nth1(I, List, E),
    index_map(I, Start, Stop, Target, P),
    nth1(P, Result, E),
    J is I + 1,
    move_elements(J, N, List, Start, Stop, Target, Result).
*/
move_elements(I, N, List, Start, Stop, Target, Result) :-
    I =< N,
    nth1(I, List, E),
    index_map(I, Start, Stop, Target, P),
    nth1(P, Result, E),
    J is I + 1,
    !, move_elements(J, N, List, Start, Stop, Target, Result).
move_elements(_I, _N, _List, _Start, _Stop, _Target, _Result).
```

We are left with the hard part: index_map *must* do some arithmetic, juggling among available positions. I think the problem is a bit underspecified so far. Here is just the basic case, covering your test query:

```
index_map(I, Start, Stop, Target, P) :-
    I >= Start,
    I =< Stop,
    P is Target - (Stop - Start + 1) + I.
index_map(_I, _Start, _Stop, _Target, _P).
```

You should add more test to specify more constraint, but note that the last clause of index_map/5 *allows* Prolog to search a *matching* element (via `nth1(P, Result, E)`), thus completing the mapping in simple way.

*edit*: With help from [foreach](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foreach/2)/2 we can avoid looping

```
move(List, Start, Stop, Target, Result) :-
    length(List, N),
    length(Result, N),
    foreach(nth1(I, List, E), assign(I, E, Start, Stop, Target, Result)).

assign(I, E, Start, Stop, Target, Result) :-
    index_map(I, Start, Stop, Target, P),
    nth1(P, Result, E).
```